# React reusable component with custom props

Tags: reactjs

I am populating a Select dropdown in a component using this code

```
export const Dropdown = props => (
  <Select placeholder={props.placeholder} onChange={onChange}>
    {Items.map(item =>
      <option key={item.key} value={item.key}>{item.value}</option>
    )};
  </Select>
)
```

I want to use this component for different GQL API which returns `item` with different parameter. Sometimes the `item.value` is `item.foo` sometimes `item.bar`. What I am trying to do, passing a props called `parameter` so that I can use this parameter in this `JSX` using `props.parameter` as `foo` or `bar`. So how can I use this `item.foo` or `item.bar` (whatever comes from props parameter) instead of `item.value`? In a nutshell How can I change the `value` parameter of `item.value` with a props value?

Comment: Are you using typescript or javascript?

Comment: Just use bracket notation to look up the variable property on the object